# "I find myself" usage

Tags: word-usage

Is this phrase correct?
 "You go home while I find myself something to eat"

or should I use:
 "You go home while I will find myself something to eat"

or

"You go home while I find something to eat for myself"

or is there some other even better version?

Comment: Idiomatically *you go home while I find myself something to eat* is the one that works. But you might say *Whilst you are gone I will be finding myself something to eat*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word 'while' typically connects two actions which are happening at the same time, so the two actions on either side of the conjunction sound best when given in the same tense:

"You will go home while I will find myself something to eat"
"You went home while I found myself something to eat"
"You go home while I find myself something to eat"
"You are going home while I am finding myself something to eat"

So your first and last statements are both acceptable whereas the second one sounds wrong.

I agree with your hesitation: "I find myself..." can have another meaning. You would say "I find myself surprised whenever I hear that song" and it doesn't literally mean you go to search for some "surprised" whenever you hear it. Your last statement deals with this nicely by changing the word order to "for myself", however I think all listeners would understand the sense of your first sentence (especially since what follows "I find myself" cannot be construed as an adjective).

So, in short, 1 or 3 but not 2.

Comment: A noun following _find myself_ in the sense of _find myself to be_ is not impossible: 'I wake up, and I find myself Duke of Algonia'.

Comment: Very good point. The sentence "I woke up with a lion, and found myself breakfast" could go either way!

Comment: What a coincidence! Yesterday, I shot an elephant in my pajamas.